# How to acess a certain Array[property] in a object?

Tags: javascript

I need to access a property that is in the array of the object. I need to Get the rowData, iterate the elements (Foreach)
at app catalog array, select "name" elements and join custom array apps.name, assign it to another property of questionnaire, make up a new name like "appNames", use this name in the ag-grid header. But I have failed to do this somehow I am missing something.

The payload I have is :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "test",
    "lastName": "customer",
    "status": 1,
    "accountType": "CUSTOMER",
    "licenseType": "BASIC",
    "questionnaire": {
        "id": 6,
        "companysize": "MICRO",
        "industry": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Agriculture and Mining"
        },
        "language": "CZ",
        "appCatalog": [
            {
                "appIdToSearch": 6,
                "appNameDefault": "SECURITY PLUS"
            },
            {
                "appIdToSearch": 121,
                "appNameDefault": "New logo test CZ"
            }
        ],
        "customApps": [
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "asd",
                "enabled": false
            },
            {
                "id": 49,
                "name": "aaaaaa",
                "enabled": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and the code I am accessing other property of the object :

```
{
  headerName: 'First Name',
  field: 'firstName',
  sortable: true,
  filter: true,
  checkboxSelection: true,
  editable: true,
  resizable: true,
},
{
  headerName: 'Last Name',
  field: 'lastName',
  sortable: true,
  filter: true,
  editable: true,
  resizable: true,
},
{
  headerName: 'Email',
  field: 'email',
  sortable: true,
  filter: true,
  editable: true,
  resizable: true,
},
{
  headerName: 'Phone',
  field: 'phone',
  sortable: true,
  filter: true,
  editable: true,
  resizable: true
},
{
  headerName: 'Employee Count',
  field: 'questionnaire.companysize',
  sortable: true,
  filter: true,
  editable: false,
  resizable: true
},
{
  headerName: 'Industry',
  field: 'questionnaire.industry.name',
  sortable: true,
  filter: true,
  editable: false,
  resizable: true
},
{
  headerName: 'Language Preference',
  field: 'questionnaire.language',
  sortable: true,
  filter: true,
  editable: false,
  resizable: true,
},
{
  headerName: 'Apps I am using',
  field: 'AppNames',
  sortable: true,
  filter: true,
  editable: false,
  resizable: true
},
```

the last one is the one i cannot access .

> this field is equal to AppNames=== 
>   `appCatalog.appNameDefault`+`customApps.name`
>   but I couldn't have it done, can anyone help me, please!!

Comment: Can you add the expected output and what you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name of your costumApp :

```
yourObject.questionnaire.appCataloge[0].forEach((item,index)=>{
    //do Staff with one item there...
    item.appNameDefault  = item.appNameDefault+' '+yourObject.questionnaire.customApps[index].name;
});
```

Comment: YEAH, but I need to join that appCatalog.appNameDefault, and by what I try I could make it, do you have an idea? @Conan

Comment: Also, I need to get all the values not just the first on those values belong to one person ... i think i need a foreach to get them , but i am stuck here ..not getting the result i want

Comment: As you see at payload appCatalog is an [] and inside this array I need appNameDefault and this result will be join with customApps [].name to form only one string
firstString = SECURITY PLUS asd ;/////
second string = New logo test CZ aaaaaa///////

Comment: This looks better but I need to get also the appCatalog.appNameDefault isn't any way I can get them at the same time
PS: for each doesn't need ++

Answer (score 1):

You can use map function of array.

```
customNames = yourObject.questionnaire.customApps.map(app => appNameDefault + app.name);
```

The customNames will contain all customApps names.

Refer MDN documentation for map function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: can you provide an example  with the payload at the question

Comment: I have provided the example of map according to the payload given and same variable names. Also added the documentation link for map function.